# How to define advance condition in each group

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have below sample data, and I'm trying to get groups of record with below conditions:

- Same `prev_read_at`
- Different `current_read_at`
- Only one record must have `payment_id`
- Number of records in each group must be greater than one
- **The record with `payment_id` must have the least `amount`**

Here is my sample data:

| id | location_id | payment_id | amount | prev_read_at | current_read_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | `null` | 237003000 | 2021-07-03 01:00:00 | 2021-09-01 01:00:00 |
| 2 | 10 | 1741 | 139664000 | 2021-07-03 01:00:00 | 2021-11-16 01:00:00 |
| 3 | 20 | `null` | 0 | 2021-07-04 01:00:00 | 2021-08-02 01:00:00 |
| 4 | 20 | 1655 | 6820000 | 2021-07-04 01:00:00 | 2021-09-06 01:00:00 |
| 5 | 20 | `null` | 39000 | 2021-07-04 01:00:00 | 2021-09-08 01:00:00 |

I've applied all conditions except the last one in below query.

```sql
select GROUP_CONCAT(id), location_id, GROUP_CONCAT(current_read_at) from bills
where prev_read_at between '2021-07-01 12:01:01' and '2021-07-05 12:01:01'
group by CONCAT(`location_id` ,`prev_read_at`)
having count(id)>1 AND count(payment_id)=1 AND COUNT(DISTINCT current_read_at)>1
```

The desirable result must contain only records with `location_id = 10`.
I think the last condition must be applied on each group, but don't know how to implement this in *having* or are there any other method for this?

Server version: 10.3.18-MariaDB - MariaDB Server

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=312a59fd7cd16525f16b5b7d112ec5f1) is the dbfiddle of my question. As you can see, I want to filter records with ids of `3,4,5` in my result. Because `3,4,5` group don't have payment_id with the least amount in its group.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! I'm having difficulty in understanding your goal(s). Please go to dbfiddle.uk and choose the MariaDB 10.3 instance there - put in your table DDL and data DML. Kindly provide us with your desired output - so that we have input -> output and explain to us the logic that you used to arrive at this output. [Images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530) are frowned upon here for the reasons outlined in the link!

Comment: @Vérace-getVACCINATEDNOW Thank you for your response. I've added a dbfiddle in the question and about images, I haven't added any images in the question.

Comment: What is the problem you are having? You appear to have written a query which returns the results that you want? I would advise against grouping of ids and current_reads as comma-delimited strings - at least if they are for anything but the presentation layer? Is it a speed issue?

Comment: As you can see in the results, the row that has `3,4,5` ids do not meet the last condition that I wrote in question. I want to omit this row in the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using window functions for applying such complex conditions. After select your criteria over different partitions, you can limit your results over those criteria. Below query is derived by considering your conditions in [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=754a330ee96b4dc089f2ad1981c52328).

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
select *,
    COUNT(payment_id) OVER (PARTITION BY prev_read_at,location_id) payed_count,
    COUNT(location_id) OVER (PARTITION BY prev_read_at,location_id) loc_count,
    min(case when payment_id is null then amount end) OVER (PARTITION BY prev_read_at,location_id) min_amt,
    min(case when payment_id is not null then amount end) OVER (PARTITION BY prev_read_at,location_id) payed_min_amt,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY location_id, prev_read_at ORDER BY current_read_at ASC) cur_rank
from bills
where prev_read_at between '2021-07-01 12:01:01' and '2021-07-05 12:01:01'
) A
    WHERE payed_count=1
    AND loc_count>payed_count
    AND payed_min_amt+1 < min_amt+1
    AND cur_rank > 1
    AND payment_id is not null;
```

Hope it works.